# Weird behavior when assigning local namerefs to local variables in functions

Tags: bash, function, variable-assignment

I have put much time in trying to understand the behavior described below, but without success. Please consider the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

function Dummy() {

  local -n namerefArray="$1"
  local -a -i myArray=("${namerefArray[@]}")

  local -p
}

declare -a -i myArray=('1' '2' '3')

Dummy 'myArray'
```

The output is:

```
root@cerberus:~/scripts# ./test6
myArray=()
namerefArray=myArray
```

That is, the assignment in the second line in the function body destroys the content of the variable which is referenced by the nameref.

Originally, this made me scratch my head until I understood that this line actually expands to

```
local -a -i myArray=("${myArray[@]}")
```

if `$1` is `myArray` as in the example. So I am assigning a (yet undefined) array variable (to be precise, its expansion) to itself.

Obviously, in a function, `bash` can't distinguish between a local variable and a nameref variable if the referenced variable has the same name as the local one. So far, so good (rather, so far, so bad, because this actually makes namerefs worthless, but this is another story and not subject of the question).

Then I tried the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

function Dummy() {

  local -n namerefArray="$1"
  local myArray=("${namerefArray[@]}")

  local -p
}

declare -a -i myArray=('1' '2' '3')

Dummy 'myArray'
```

Please note that it is literally the same as the first example, except that `-a -i` is missing in the second line of the function body.

But now the output is:

```
root@cerberus:~/scripts# ./test6
myArray=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3")
namerefArray=myArray
```

That is, this time the array has been copied as expected, and the variable referenced by the nameref has not been emptied.

Could somebody please explain why `-a -i` in the second line of the function body makes such an important difference? I'd really like to understand it.

**UPDATE**

This originally happened with `bash 4.2.12` in an up-to-date vanilla debian stretch installation. **In the meantime, I have tried it with `bash 5.0.3` in an up-to-date debian buster installation, with exactly the same result.**

I can hardly imagine that such a bug could go unresolved for at least 3 years, so it perhaps is intended behavior?

**UPDATE 2**

In the meantime, I even tried with `bash 5.0.11`, with the same result.

Comment: Thank you very much. For clarification, what exactly is the bug? Is the bug that the first example does not work, or is the bug that the second example *does* work?

Comment: Thanks again. Please see my update in the question. I have tried it with bash 5.0.3, with the exact same result. I'll try to follow your advice and build bash myself, although I can hardly imagine that a bug like this could survive several years, so perhaps it is intended behavior.

Comment: In the meantime, I tried with bash 5.0.11, with the same result.

Comment: I have filed a bug report. Let's see how long it takes until it appears in the official list of bugs.

Comment: I have sent it to bash@packages.debian.org and to bug-bash@gnu.org ... According to the log files on our mail server, delivery was successful via relay eggs.gnu.org

Comment: I just have noticed that I probably will have to subscribe to that list before my messages to it get processed. The help message in bashbug did not mention this. Sorry about that. I have subscribed to the list now. Should I re-send the bug report, or will the previous message get through automatically (now that I am subscribed)?

Comment: it's now in the list: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2020-08/msg00154.html